# Show that given two marked points, Euclid can draw a circle centered at one of them and passing through the other.

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-construction

This is problem 6 of 37th Indian National Mathematical Olympiad - 2023.

> Euclid has a tool called cyclos which allows him to do the following:
>
> - Given three non-collinear marked points, draw the circle passing through them.
> - Given two marked points, draw the circle with them as endpoints of a diameter.
> - Mark any intersection points of two drawn circles or mark a new point on a
>   drawn circle.
>
> Show that given two marked points, Euclid can draw a circle centered at one of them
> and passing through the other, using only the cyclos.

In case you might think otherwise, the name "Euclid" in the problem just refers to a generic person who loves geometry.

I can prove it without the use of cyclos by the method of contradiction.

By taking two points $A,B$ such that they didn't satisfy the given question condition. And marked the midpoint of them and then drew a circle as an extremity of diameter with the center of their midpoint and then took reflection of $B$ from a line passing through $A$ and perpendicular to $AB$ as $B'$. Taking radii $AB'$ and it will pass through $B$. But I am unable to prove by cyclos.

Comment: [[1]] It is **unnecessarily** confusing when using the name "Euclid" involving Euclidean geometry. Suggest changing to "A Geometer" with a new "geometric tool Cyclos" [[2]] Which Contest gave this Puzzle ?

Comment: @Prem INMO 2023

Comment: Interesting Puzzle [ +1 ] It might have no Solution : Proving it might be the Challenge here !

Comment: @Prem I think there's no problem if we keep the original wording when we ask Olympiad questions.

Comment: (1) That is correct when the Post (or at least the title) starts like this "INMO 2023 has this Puzzle : ...." (2) When I first saw the title , I thought it was some historical Issue where Euclid used some unknown tool Cyclos. When I probed , I got the connection to INMO 2023. (3) There was at least 1 other Deleted Comment where the user was similarly confused. (4) "Now" when you see John , you can easily change it to Euclid without confusion , but "Earlier" you too would have been confused. @youthdoo

Comment: Has INMO **2023** already ended?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, yes it has ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us collect the operations (Ops) that cyclos (or John if you prefer) can do besides the given operations. Call a line **a drawn line** if there are at least two mark points on it. We also say cyclos can "draw" that line.

**Op foot**: Suppose $a$ is a marked point and $\ell$ is a drawn line. Then cyclos can mark the foot of perpendicular from $a$ to $\ell$.

**Op perpendicular**: Suppose $a$ is a marked point and $\ell$ is a drawn line ($a$ might be on $\ell$). Then cyclos can draw the line through $a$ that is perpendicular to $\ell$.

**Op far**: Suppose $a,b$ are two marked points. Then cyclos can mark a point that is far away from line $\ell$ that passes $a,b$. All we need is that the distance between the new point and $\ell$ is at least $\|\overline{ab}\|$, which is the distance between $a$ and $b$.

**Op midpoint**: Suppose $a,b$ are two marked points. Then cyclos can mark the midpoint of $a,b$.

**Op $\frac14$ away**: Suppose $a,b$ are two marked points. Then cyclos can mark a point that is $\frac14\|\overline{ab}\|$ away from line $ab$.

**Op rotate $90°$**: Suppose $a,b$ are two marked points. Then cyclos can mark a point that together with $a,b$ form an isosceles right triangle with $b$ at the right angle.

**Op double**: Suppose $a,b$ are two marked points. Then cyclos can mark the point $c$ such that $b$ is the midpoint of $a$ and $c$.

**Op compass**: Suppose $a,b$ are two marked points. Then cyclos can draw a circle that is centered $b$ and passing $a$. This is the operation that we are asked to show.

---

Here is how cyclos can do the operations above.

Op foot: Let $b,c$ are two marked points on $\ell$. Draw the circle with diameter $\overline{ab}$ and circle with diameter $\overline{ac}$. Mark the intersection of the two circles, which is the foot of perpendicular from $a$ to $\ell$.

Op perpendicular: Let $b,c$ are two marked points on $\ell$. Draw the circle with diameter $\overline{bc}$. Mark a point $d$ on the circle that is neither $b$ nor $c$. Mark point $e$, the foot of perpendicular from $d$ to $\ell$.

- If $e$ is $a$, line $ad$ is the wanted line.
- Otherwise draw a similar line $\overline{fg}$ that is perpendicular to $\ell$. Mark $h$, the foot of perpendicular from $d$ to $\overline{fg}$. Mark $i$, the foot of perpendicular from $a$ to line $\overline{dh}$. The line $\overline{ai}$ is what we wanted.

Op far: this is obvious and probably not interesting to most readers, so I will omit how cyclos can achieve it, although it take a while to show a random algorithm with high probablity and it takes much longer to show a deterministic one.

Op midpoint: Mark $c$, a point that is far away from line $\overline{ab}$. Draw line $\ell_a$ and $\ell_b$ that are perpendicular to $\overline{ab}$, passing through $a$ and $b$ respectively. Mark the foot of perpendicular from $c$ to $\ell_a$ and to $\ell_b$, namely $d$ and $e$ respectively. Draw the circles with diameter $\overline{ad}$ and $\overline{be}$ respectively. Mark $e$, one of the intersection point of two circles. Mark the foot of perpendicular from $e$ to line $\overline{ab}$. $e$ is the midpoint of  $\overline{ab}$.

Op $\frac14$ away: Mark $c$, the midpoint of $a$ and $b$. Mark the midpoint of $a$ and $c$ as well as the midpoint of $c$ and $b$. Repeat until all points on line segment $\overline{ab}$ that are $\frac i{16}$ away from $a$ are marked, assuming WLOG the length of line segment $\overline{ab}$ is $1$. Draw the circle with diameter that ends at $a$ and the marked point that is $\frac{10}{16}$ away from $a$. Draw the circle with diameter that ends at $b$ and the marked point that is $\frac{10}{16}$ away from $b$. Mark $x$, one of the intersection points of two circles. Then $x$ is a wanted point.

Op rotate $90°$**: Mark $x$, a point that is $\frac14\|\overline{ab}\|$ away from line $ab$. Mark $d$, the foot of perpendicular from $x$ to the line that is through $b$ and perpendicular to line $ab$. Note that we just rotated $\frac14$ of line segment $\|\overline{ab}\|$ $90°$ to $\overline{bd}$.
Mark $c$, the foot of perpendicular from $d$ to the line that is through $a$ and perpendicular to line $ab$. Then $abdc$ is a rectangle. We can, similarly, rotate $\frac14$ of line segment $\|\overline{cd}\|$ to $\overline{df}$.  Repeat two more times to get $\overline{fh}$ and $\overline{hj}$. The $j$ is the wanted point.

Op double: Apply op rotate $90°$ two times.

Op compass: Apply op double to mark point $c$. Draw the circle with diameter $\overline{ac}$. This is the wanted circle.

(Graphs will come soon.)